# How to display “no results found” using Searchview

Tags: android, searchview

Here is my code in "if (query == null)." As you can see, I don't put any code there because I don't know how to display "no result(s) found" in the RecyclerView if the user doesn't match his input to the searchview. I'm using RecyclerView to display the search results of the user.

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));


    // listening to search query text change
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // filter recycler view when query submitted
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // filter recycler view when text is changed
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }
    });

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

in the adapter

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                categoriesFiltered = categorieslist;
            } else {
                List<CategoriesP> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (CategoriesP row : categorieslist) {

                    // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                    // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                    //|| row.getPhone().contains(charSequence)
                    if (row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }

                categoriesFiltered = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = categoriesFiltered;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
            categoriesFiltered = (ArrayList<CategoriesP>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I think a Toast will do the job. Don't have to complicate things with different views in same adapter.

Comment: You can control visibility of your textView from the adapter.Add Text view in your activity.

Comment: You can basically use a Toast to show the result that is "No results found" or if you want something different then you can can use Lottie file or a sort of image and display that Lottie file or image when the result is "No result found" otherwise set their visibility to "Gone". But using Toast for this situation is considered as best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Set TextView in your XML and set this line `android:visibility="gone"` for it.

in your Activity put this code...

```
if (listMesage.isEmpty()) {
     mRecyclerMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     mTxtEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
    else {
     mRecyclerMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     mTxtEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
```